# adding two stamps/watermarks to document

Tags: watermark

I would like to add to stamps to my document; one only on the first page, the other on all pages. I would also like to have it all specified in  the header of the document.

I started out with the

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{%
  pages=all,
  scale=1,
  opacity=1.0,
  color =black,
  contents={my content}
}

\begin{document}
abc\newpage
def
\end{document}
```

which works alright for one stamp. I can't seem to find a way to add a second stamp though.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

You need to 
issue a second 
`\backgroundsetup` command for the second stamp.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{%
  pages=some, scale=1, opacity=1.0, color =black, 
  contents={my content},
  firstpage=true
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\newpage

\backgroundsetup{%
  pages=all, scale=1, opacity=1.0, color=red,
  contents={from second page},
}

\lipsum[21-40]

\end{document}
```

**Knowledge Base**

As is stated in the [`background` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/background/background.pdf),

> For a later change of options, this package provides the command
>
> ```
> \backgroundsetup{ options }
> ```

Also, as stated in the same document,

> `firstpage`= This boolean option allows the user to specify, setting
>   the value true, that the
>             background material must be displayed only in the first page of the document.
>              The deafulat value is *false*.

**Output**

---

[image] |  [image]

---

**Observation**

As 
I found out by trial and error, a subsequent 
`\backgroundsetup` seem to be working *only* after a `\newpage`. The documentation examples follow the same line without stating the reason behind this.

Anybody has any input on this issue?